# Using Django with the Drizzle database?

Tags: django, drizzle

Has anyone experience in using Django with the Drizzle database?

The first GA version of Drizzle has just been released and from my understanding it should be be a good match for Django. Being a stripped down version of MySQL it still provides all the needed functionality and hopefully a better performance.

Answer (score 2):

To use the Django MySQL backend, [you have to install the MySQLdb driver](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/databases/#mysqldb). When I install MySQLdb on a machine that has Drizzle installed (but not MySQL), I get this error: `EnvironmentError: mysql_config not found`.  I believe this is the step where MySQLdb is looking for [compiler options to build the client](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysql-config.html).  We probably need a fork of the Django MySQL backend that uses a Python wrapper around libdrizzle.

Answer (score 1):

MySQLdb is playing just fine with Drizzle.  We use it to work with SQLAlchemy.
I can't speak to the issues you encountered, but I also tend to have both MySQL and Drizzle on my machines.  Things built ok for me, but I'd be happy to help resolve any issues anyone else is having